# Keras AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'log'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am having an error - 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'log' that I code in Keras to build a network while apply custom loss function to Keras. I think somehow I need to get rid of np.log but not sure how.

```
import Numpy 

import numpy as np
```

Custom Function

```
def rmsle(y_pred,y_test):
   return np.sqrt(np.mean((np.log(1+y_pred) - np.log(1+y_test))**2))
```

My network

```
def base_model():
   model = Sequential()
   model.add(Dense(50, input_dim=X_train.shape[1], init='normal',     activation='sigmoid'))
   model.add(Dropout(0.5))

   model.add(Dense(1, init='normal'))
   sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, momentum=0.8, decay=0.1, nesterov=False)
   model.compile(loss=rmsle, optimizer = sgd)# )'adam') #
   return model

keras = KerasRegressor(build_fn=base_model, nb_epoch=80, batch_size=1,verbose=1)
keras.fit(X_train ,y_train)
```

When i check the error msg in detail, it shows that

```
424         """
425         # score_array has ndim >= 2
--> 426         score_array = fn(y_true, y_pred)
427         if mask is not None:
428             # Cast the mask to floatX to avoid float64 upcasting in theano
2     #return np.sqrt(np.mean(np.square( np.log( (np.exp(a)) + 1 ) - np.log((np.exp(b))+1) )))
----> 4     return np.sqrt(np.mean((np.log(1+y_pred) - np.log(1+y_test))**2))
2     #return np.sqrt(np.mean(np.square( np.log( (np.exp(a)) + 1 ) - np.log((np.exp(b))+1) )))
```

Comment: Please show how you import `numpy`, ideally show us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem. My first suspicion would be that you re-assign `np` to something other than `numpy`, so that instead of calling `numpy.log`, you are trying to call whatever Keras object you assigned to `np`.

Comment: Hi thx for reply. i have called numpy as import numpy as np

Comment: Can you show the whole code? Your snippet is at least missing the import statements. For debugging, you can put a `print(type(np), np.__file__)` into your loss function to check that `np` really is the `numpy` module.

Comment: Also, can you please show the error message and the stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use valid tensor operations from your backend (i.e. from [keras.backend](https://keras.io/backend/)) in order to define a custom loss function. For example, your loss function could be defined as follows:

```
import keras.backend as K

def rmsle(y_test, y_pred):
    return K.sqrt(K.mean(K.square(K.log(1 + y_pred) - K.log(1 + y_test))))
```

**NOTE:** Keras expects the first argument to be `y_test` (alias the ground truth).

Answer (score 0):

Lambda layers in Keras help you to implement functionality that is not prebuilt and which do not require trainable weights. So you get this liberty to implement your own logic as in this case 'Log'

This can also be done using keras `Lambda` layer as below:

```
from keras.layers import Lambda
import keras.backend as K
```

Define your function here:

```
def logFun(x):
   return keras.backend.log(x)
```

And later create a lambda layer:

```
model.add(Lambda(logFun, ...))
```

Comment: thx for helping man, it gives me idea how to solve it. thx again